# texture in material preview differs from rendered preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

My minecraft character's head has the preferred texture in material preview but it is pink in (cycles/eevee) rendered view.

[image] [image]

Comment: Maybe check your uv map or look to see if the location of your picture file has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the location of the skin image hasn't changed. If it has, try putting the skin on the character again.